# AbortError - Screen Sharing using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to implement Screen sharing functionality using webrtc. In firefox it is working, **but in chrome it showing "Abort Error"**

```
var constraints = {
    video: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: 'screen'
            },
            optional: []
          },
    audio: true,
  };

  if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(getUserMediaSuccess).catch(errorHandler);
  } else {
    alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
  }
```

console error:

```
{name: "AbortError", message: "Error starting screen capture", constraint: undefined, toString: ƒ}
```

Comment: What browser plugin you use for screen sharing?

Comment: Do I need any plugin for this?

Comment: this code is working for Firefox without any plugin. In chrome it is not. Looks like a security issue. I tried with opening chrome --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing. this one also not working

Answer (score 1):

here you are trying to access 'getUserMedia' and your target is 'screen'.

Solution:

So you need to make use of 'getDisplayMedia'
And your constraints will be like:

var constraints = {
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  };

Try this.
This will solve your problem.